# Not able to fetch multiple objects from PHP Json to Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

How to load names from these objects in ajax Javascript of JSON.

```
{"name":"Mehta","email":"aman@gmail.com"}{"name":"Jack","email":"jack@gmail.com"}{"name":"Oggy","email":"oggy@gmail.com"}
```

Comment: Please go read [ask] first of all, and then edit your question accordingly. Right now it is very hard to understand what you even want to know. (Although, should this boil down to yet another “I have no idea how to handle simple nested data structures” question, you should perhaps rather go and work through some beginner’s tutorials first. Explaining such _basics_ over and over again should not be the job of SO in the first place.)

Answer (score 1):

from the given values,  there is some missing character.   For multiple values,  please use comma separated and open and close bracket [].  Below is the example :

```
[
    {
        "name":"Mehta",
        "email":"aman@gmail.com"
    }, 
    {
        "name":"Jack",
        "email":"jack@gmail.com"
    },
    {
        "name":"Oggy",
        "email":"oggy@gmail.com"
    }
]
```

Hope it helps